# boost::spirit::karma grammar: Comma delimited output from struct with optionals attributes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-fusion, boost-spirit-karma

I need a comma delimited output from a struct with optionals. For example, if I have this struct:

```
MyStruct 
{ 
    boost::optional<std::string> one;
    boost::optional<int> two;
    boost::optional<float> three;
};
```

An output like: *{ "string", 1, 3.0 }* or *{ "string" }* or *{ 1, 3.0 }* and so on.

Now, I have code like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    boost::optional<std::string> one;
    boost::optional<int> two;
    boost::optional<float> three;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(MyStruct,
one,
two,
three)

template<typename Iterator>
struct MyKarmaGrammar : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<Iterator, MyStruct()>
{
    MyKarmaGrammar() : MyKarmaGrammar::base_type(request_)
    {
        using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
        namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

        using karma::int_;
        using karma::double_;
        using karma::string;
        using karma::lit;
        using karma::_r1;

        key_ = '"' << string(_r1) << '"';

        str_prop_ = key_(_r1) << ':' 
            << string
            ;

        int_prop_ = key_(_r1) << ':' 
            << int_
            ;

        dbl_prop_ = key_(_r1) << ':' 
            << double_
            ;

        //REQUEST
        request_ = '{'
            <<  -str_prop_("one"s) <<
                -int_prop_("two"s) <<
                -dbl_prop_("three"s)
            << '}'
            ;
    }

private:
    //GENERAL RULES
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<Iterator, void(std::string)> key_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<Iterator, double(std::string)> dbl_prop_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<Iterator, int(std::string)> int_prop_;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<Iterator, std::string(std::string)> str_prop_;

    //REQUEST
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<Iterator, MyStruct()> request_;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

    MyStruct request = {std::string("one"), 2, 3.1};

    std::string generated;
    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(generated);

    MyKarmaGrammar<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>> serializer;

    boost::spirit::karma::generate(sink, serializer, request);

    std::cout << generated << std::endl;
}
```

This works but I need a comma delimited output. I tried with a grammar like:

```
request_ = '{'
    <<  (str_prop_("one"s) |
        int_prop_("two"s) |
        dbl_prop_("three"s)) % ','
    << '}'
    ;
```

But I receive this compile error:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/container.hpp:194:52: error: no type named ‘const_iterator’ in ‘struct MyStruct’
         typedef typename Container::const_iterator type;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct is not a container, therefore list-`operator%` will not work. The documentation states it expects the attribute to be a container type.

So, just like in the Qi counterpart [I showed you to create a conditional `delim` production](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43381995/85371):

```
 delim         = (&qi::lit('}')) | ',';
```

You'd need something similar here. However, everything about it is reversed. Instead of "detecting" the end of the input sequence from the presence of a `{`, we need to track the absense of preceding field from "not having output a field since opening brace yet".

That's a bit trickier since the required state cannot come from the same source as the input. We'll use a parser-member for simplicity here¹:

```
private:
  bool _is_first_field;
```

Now, when we generate the opening brace, we want to initialize that to `true`:

```
    auto _f = px::ref(_is_first_field); // short-hand
    request_ %= lit('{') [ _f = true ]
```

> ***Note**: Use of `%=` instead of `=` tells Spirit that we want automatic attribute propagation to happen, in spite of the presence of a Semantic Action (`[ _f = true ]`)*.

Now, we need to generate the delimiter:

```
    delim = eps(_f) | ", ";
```

Simple. Usage is also simple, except we'll want to *conditionally* `reset` the `_f`:

```
    auto reset = boost::proto::deep_copy(eps [ _f = false ]);

    str_prop_ %= (delim << key_(_r1) << string  << reset) | ""; 
    int_prop_ %= (delim << key_(_r1) << int_    << reset) | ""; 
    dbl_prop_ %= (delim << key_(_r1) << double_ << reset) | "";
```

A very subtle point here is that I changed to the declared rule attribute types from `T` to *`optional<T>`*. This allows Karma to do the magic to fail the value generator if it's empty (`boost::none`), and skipping the `reset`!

```
ka::rule<Iterator, boost::optional<double>(std::string)> dbl_prop_;
ka::rule<Iterator, boost::optional<int>(std::string)> int_prop_;
ka::rule<Iterator, boost::optional<std::string>(std::string)> str_prop_;
```

Now, let's put together some testcases:

### Test Cases

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa3f5a148e124200)</kbd>**

```
#include "iostream"
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <string>

struct MyStruct {
    boost::optional<std::string> one;
    boost::optional<int> two;
    boost::optional<double> three;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, one, two, three)

namespace ka = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

template<typename Iterator>
struct MyKarmaGrammar : ka::grammar<Iterator, MyStruct()> {
    MyKarmaGrammar() : MyKarmaGrammar::base_type(request_) {
        using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

        using ka::int_;
        using ka::double_;
        using ka::string;
        using ka::lit;
        using ka::eps;
        using ka::_r1;

        auto _f    = px::ref(_is_first_field);
        auto reset = boost::proto::deep_copy(eps [ _f = false ]);

        key_ = '"' << string(_r1) << "\":";

        delim = eps(_f) | ", ";

        str_prop_ %= (delim << key_(_r1) << string  << reset) | ""; 
        int_prop_ %= (delim << key_(_r1) << int_    << reset) | ""; 
        dbl_prop_ %= (delim << key_(_r1) << double_ << reset) | ""; 

        //REQUEST
        request_ %= lit('{') [ _f = true ]
            <<  str_prop_("one"s) <<
                int_prop_("two"s) <<
                dbl_prop_("three"s)
            << '}';
    }

  private:
    bool _is_first_field = true;
    //GENERAL RULES
    ka::rule<Iterator, void(std::string)> key_;
    ka::rule<Iterator, boost::optional<double>(std::string)> dbl_prop_;
    ka::rule<Iterator, boost::optional<int>(std::string)> int_prop_;
    ka::rule<Iterator, boost::optional<std::string>(std::string)> str_prop_;
    ka::rule<Iterator> delim;

    //REQUEST
    ka::rule<Iterator, MyStruct()> request_;
};

template <typename T> std::array<boost::optional<T>, 2> option(T const& v) {
    return { { v, boost::none } };
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

    for (auto a : option("one"s))
    for (auto b : option(2))
    for (auto c : option(3.1))
    for (auto request : { MyStruct { a, b, c } }) {
        std::string generated;
        std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(generated);

        MyKarmaGrammar<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>> serializer;

        ka::generate(sink, serializer, request);

        std::cout << boost::fusion::as_vector(request) << ":\t" << generated << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
( one  2  3.1): {"one":one, "two":2, "three":3.1}
( one  2 --):   {"one":one, "two":2}
( one --  3.1): {"one":one, "three":3.1}
( one -- --):   {"one":one}
(--  2  3.1):   {"two":2, "three":3.1}
(--  2 --):     {"two":2}
(-- --  3.1):   {"three":3.1}
(-- -- --):     {}
```

---

¹ Note this limits re-entrant use of the parser, as well as making it non-const etc. `karma::locals` are the true answer to that, adding a little more complexity

Comment: I've thought that BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT transforms your struct to a iterable (my bad). Thanks sehe